# How to do video capturing of an Android device screen?

Tags: android, screen, share, capture

I would like to know whether there any application or a method to video capture the screen of an Android device. Also is there any software to share the screen of an Android device with the PC.

Thank you.

Comment: Not a programming question; belongs on [Android StackExchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 3):

Screencast will do the job for you. It takes video capture of your Android device. :

Free

[Screencast Video Recorder Demo](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencastfree)

Paid

[Screencast Video Recorder](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.ms.screencast)